# Convert NOT IN query to LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, left-join, netezza

to adapt to Netezza DB I need to convert fallowing query(as NOT IN(SUBQUERY) is not supported by Netezza):

```
UPDATE table1 t1 SET t1.deal_type=t2.deal_type 
FROM  table2 t2
WHERE t1.id_col=t2.id_col 
AND t1.price=t2.price
AND t1.id_col2=t2.id_col2
AND t2.price NOT IN (
  SELECT st1.price
  FROM table1 st1, table2 st2
  WHERE st1.id_col=st2.id_col 
  AND st1.price=st2.price
  AND st1.id_col2=st2.id_col2
  AND st1.id_col=t1.id_col
  AND t2.deal_type=st2.deal_type
  GROUP BY st1.id_col, st1.price, st1.id_col2, st2.deal_type
  HAVING COUNT (*)>1);
```

I tried with LEFT JOIN but not all records returned:

```
UPDATE table1 t1 SET t1.deal_type = t2.deal_type
FROM table2 t2 
LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT st1.price, st1.id_col, st2.deal_type
   FROM table1 st1, table2 st2
   WHERE st1.id_col=st2.id_col 
   AND st1.price=st2.price
   AND st1.id_col2=st2.id_col2
   GROUP BY st1.id_col, st1.price, st1.id_col2, st2.deal_type
   HAVING COUNT (*)>1) subq ON (subq.id_col=t1.id_col
   AND t2.deal_type=subq.deal_type)
WHERE 
 t1.id_col=t2.id_col 
 AND t1.price=t2.price
 AND t1.id_col2=t2.id_col2
 subq.price is null
```

Any suggestions where I was wrong. or any other way to work arround NOT IN witch is not supported by NETEZZA

Comment: Are you sure that `NOT IN` is not supported (I would be very surprised), or is it simply that you cannot use a ***correlated*** subquery with `NOT IN`?  Big difference. What is the exact error message that you get with your first statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to add the price to the Left Join condition.

if there are duplicates for this id&type but with different price,
the NOT-IN condition will pass, but the Left-Join (IS NULL) condition will fail

just change

```
ON (subq.id_col=t1.id_col
   AND t2.deal_type=subq.deal_type)
```

to

```
ON (subq.id_col=t1.id_col
  AND t2.deal_type=subq.deal_type)
  AND subq.price=t2.price)
```

Comment: thanks alot, that worked !! I was stuck on this for few days going back to this time to time and not figureing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this if netezza support EXISTS and your first query is logically right

```
UPDATE t1 SET t1.deal_type=t2.deal_type 
FROM  table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id_col=t2.id_col 
    AND t1.price=t2.price
    AND t1.id_col2=t2.id_col2
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT st1.id_col
        FROM table1 st1
        INNER JOIN table2 st2 ON st1.id_col=st2.id_col 
            AND st1.price=st2.price
            AND st1.id_col2=st2.id_col2
            AND t2.deal_type=st2.deal_type
        GROUP BY st1.id_col, st1.price, st1.id_col2, st2.deal_type
        HAVING COUNT (*)>1) i ON i.id_col=t1.id_col
WHERE i.id_col IS NULL
```

Comment: While your suggestion works on Sybase it does not work in Netezza. Same error: 
 "This form of correlated query is not supported - consider rewriting"

Comment: Please check it with updated one above, I have converted it in join.

Comment: Cant use table t2 in join subquery  (AND t2.deal_type=st2.deal_type)

I took that join on  ON clause but it still gave slightly different count of records returned. Same as my try with left join

Comment: So, can you please share schema and expected output.